# RecyclerView's DiffUtils produces strange overlapping Items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a simple RecyclerView and Adapter that looks like this:

[image: Normal view]

Then I want to reorder an item (move at another position) after the users clicks on a button. i.e. I want to move the item in the violett box at another position.
[image]

So I change the item in the adapters dataset and `DiffUtils` to let the move animation be done.

But at the end of the animation the screen looks like this:

[image]

as you see: the item is overlapping with another item:

[image]

I have debugged my DiffUtil Callback implementation and everything is working properly. Also dispatching is working as expected. I have added some logs:

```
 data.getDiffResult().dispatchUpdatesTo(new ListUpdateCallback() {
          @Override public void onInserted(int position, int count) {
            Log.d("Test", "Insert position "+position+" count "+count);
          }

          @Override public void onRemoved(int position, int count) {
            Log.d("Test", "Removed removed "+position+" count "+count);
          }

          @Override public void onMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
            Log.d("Test", "Moved position "+fromPosition+" to " +toPosition);
          }

          @Override public void onChanged(int position, int count, Object payload) {
            Log.d("Test", "Changed position "+position+" count "+count);
          }
        });
```

Then logcat prints the expected (correct) result

> Moved position 3 to 8
>
> Changed position 8 count 1

Is it really a RecyclerView bug? Has anybody faced the same issue?
I tried RecyclerView version `24.2.0` and `25.0.0`, both have the same behavior and incorrect result in the UI.

Comment: Having that same problem. Have you solved it yet?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet

Comment: Any luck? I can't figure this out with the new AndroidX library